# Akka java never close over a ActorRef

Tags: java, akka, future

I dont understand this statement about closing over the actor ref in the callback.
Currently I am using

```
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
        ActorRef senderActorRef = getSender(); //never close over a future
        if (message instanceof String) {
            Future<String> f =akka.dispatch.Futures.future(new Callable<String>() {
                public String call() {
                    String value= jedisWrapper.getString("name");
                    senderActorRef.tell((String) message,ActorRef.noSender());
                    return "what";
                }
            }, ex);
            f.onSuccess(new OnSuccessExtension(), ex);
        }
    }

private final class OnSuccessExtension extends OnSuccess {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Object arg0) throws Throwable {
            log.info("what");
        }
    }
```

Is this the right way to use it?
How can I pass the Sender Actor ref in the OnSuccess method? 
Also whats the difference between onSuccess and OnComplete ? 
If I want to use onComplete how would I use it?

Answer: Pass the Sender Actor Ref in the constructor. The answer given by another user. 
OnSuccess is a specialized form of OnComplete. 
OnComplete useage from Akka docs

```
final ExecutionContext ec = system.dispatcher();
future.onComplete(new OnComplete<String>() {
public void onComplete(Throwable failure, String result) {
if (failure != null) {
//We got a failure, handle it here
} else {
// We got a result, do something with it
}
}
}, ec);
```

Comment: The way you're doing it is fine.  The race condition only arises if you call `getSender()` from within the `OnSuccess` method.

Comment: Can I use getSelf in the onSuccess method? It wont be a race condition as its always going to be the same actor?

Comment: `getSelf` is safe but it's possible the actor could be dead at that point and the message will end up in the dead letters queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it in the constructor:

```
public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    final ActorRef senderActorRef = getSender(); //never close over a future
    if (message instanceof String) {
        Future<String> f = // ...
        f.onSuccess(new OnSuccessExtension(senderActorRef), ex);
    }
}

private final class OnSuccessExtension extends OnSuccess {
    private final ActorRef senderActorRef;

    public OnSuccessExtension(ActorRef senderActorRef) {
        this.senderActorRef = senderActorRef;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Object arg0) throws Throwable {
        log.info("what");
        // use senderActorRef
    }
}
```

Comment: What about using an anonymous inner class instead of extending the class ? How would I be able to get the sender actor ref there ?

Comment: You could access in from inside the anonymous class as long as long you declare the ``senderActorRef`` to be ``final``